# Observer fires too early

Tags: ember.js

I have three drop-downs in my view. While preparing a controller, I am doing the following:

1. Pre-set the bound properties (selectedCountry, selectedSubtype, selectedCity) (`this.set('selectedCountry', 'DE');`)
2. *After* the properties are set, I add observers for those properties, so that the drop-downs can be re-configured whenever the user is changing the selection. I am careful to add the observers after I have initialized the properties, so that I am not firing the controllers accidentally.

But, as soon as the view is rendered, the observers are **immediately** fired. The user has performed **no action** yet. I do not understand this, but I imagine that, when rendering the view in the DOM, ember sets the bound property in the drop-downs, and this causes the observers to fire. That is:

1. Ember renders the view
2. Sees the binding in the template, to the controller property
3. Sets the DOM element property according to the controller property
4. And this somehow causes the firing of the observer?!? why!?!?

If this is the case, the only solution that I can think of, would be to configure the observers **after** the view has been rendered. There is a `didInsertElement` for `Views`, but my problem is controller-related. So, I am confused: is the job of the controller to care about rendering issues? I do not think so: that should be the view's responsibility! But the controller is clearly affected by the rendering order! How to solve this in a clean way?

Comment: Can you show example code of your observer, it should be possible to implement the observer this way that it behaves differently on first call.

Comment: I'd need to see a jsbin to give you more exact details.  Observes is a little special, especially since it fires immediately when a change has occurred, it doesn't wait til the end of the run loop or anything like that.  I wouldn't imagine the binding is firing it, but I'd have to see code to be more precise.  On that note, you might try throwing some logging in the observes to see what the value is each time it hits.